# Changing default element type in Abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

The default element chosen by Abaqus is C3D8R and I would like to change that to C3D8I. 
I know how to change the element type in CAE or even recursively using Python, but not the default value.

The issue is that when I partition and re-mesh, my previous selection gets overwritten and the default C3D8R are generated.

Thanks,

R.

EDIT: 
Thanks to Fernando C. from the Simulia community the following tweak can be used. Still looking for a better solution though!

> Remy,
>
> I think the default element is hard-coded and so we don't have a setting that you can change.
>
> But don't despair. You can use methodCallback to change it automatically after the part/instance is created.
>
> You can put this in an abaqus_v6.env file so it is always doing that.
>
> ```
> import methodCallback
>
> from abaqus import *
>
> from abaqusConstants import *
>
> def changeDefaultElementType(callingObject, arguments, keywordArguments, userData):
>
>     print 'Changing the default element type'
>
>     p = getMethodReturnValue()
>
>     p.setElementType(
>
>         elemTypes=(
>
>             ElemType(elemCode=C3D8I, elemLibrary=STANDARD, secondOrderAccuracy=OFF, distortionControl=DEFAULT),
>
>             ElemType(elemCode=C3D6, elemLibrary=STANDARD),
>
>             ElemType(elemCode=C3D4, elemLibrary=STANDARD)
>
>             ),
>
>         regions=(p.cells.getSequenceFromMask(('[#1 ]', ), ), )
>
>         )
>
> methodCallback.addCallback(ModelType, 'Part', changeDefaultElementType, callAfter=True)
> ```
>
> The example is a little rough, you might want to polish it a little
>   more (For example changing the element type only for 3d parts, etc).

Comment: send your resume to simulia?

Comment: My resume or my question? 
My question is also posted in the simulia community: https://swym.3ds.com/#community:73/iquestions:35658
But I thought I'd reach a larger audience here.
My resume is available here: https://www.linkedin.com/in/remyrouxditbuisson/

As you can see, they already have it ;)

Comment: Sorry for being flip. I Mean I think you would need to work for the company to change the default.

Comment: @agentp I thought that stackoverflow was a platform where questions were taken seriously and answered constructively.

Comment: i guess not everyone has a sense of humor. Anyway you might post your answer as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the default element type will be available in Abaqus/CAE 2018.

In the meantime, the following function can be added to the custom_v6.env. (C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\SimulationServices\V6R2017x\Abaqus\win_b64\SMA\site\custom_v6.env)

```
def onCaeStartup():
    import methodCallback
    from mesh import ElemType
    from job import ModelJobType

    ## Function to be called when an input file is written
    def checkElementType(callingObject, arguments, keywordArguments, userData):
        print 'Checking element types in the model'

        # Get the name of the job from the command
        a = str(callingObject).split("jobs['")[1]
        job = a.split("']")[0]

        model = mdb.jobs[job].model
        ra    = mdb.models[model].rootAssembly

        # Query the Element Types in the assembly and display them
        elemType=[]
        for instance in ra.instances.keys():    
            for cell in ra.instances[instance].cells:
                if ra.getElementType(region=cell,elemShape=HEX).elemCode not in elemType:
                    elemType.append(ra.getElementType(region=cell,elemShape=HEX).elemCode)
                    print 'INSTANCE: '+instance +' = '+ ra.getElementType(region=cell,elemShape=HEX).elemCode

    # Define the callback. When the writeInput method is called on a ModelJobType object, the function checkElementType is executed.                
    methodCallback.addCallback(ModelJobType, 'writeInput', checkElementType)
```